# Codeigniter 4 - Attempt to read property "bannerimg" on bool while fetching images from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-applications, codeigniter-4

So I am creating carousel for my web application I am using new CodeIgniter 4. So far I have successfully managed to upload images however I can't seem to fetch images to display it on front end. It gives me following error - **Attempt to read property "bannerimg" on bool.**

**Edit** - I am trying to fetch all images from database (currently there are 4 images stored)

**My database table**

[Database table for carousel - Please check this image too!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBGfo.png)

Here is the code below

**Function to get images in AdminModel**

```
    //This functions gets the images from db
public function getBanner() {

                $builder = $this->db->table('tblbanner');
                $result = $builder->get();

                if(count($result->getResultArray()) == 1) {

                        return $result->getRow();

                } else {

                        return false;
                        
                }

        }
```

**Admin Controller**

```
public function banners() 

    {
        if(!session()->has('logged_staff')) {

                return redirect()->to(base_url(). "/team");
    
        }
        $data = [];
        $data['validation'] = null;
        $suid = session()->get('logged_staff');

        $data['getad'] = $this->adminModel->getBanner(); // This line of fetches the images from database.
        $data['staffdata'] = $this->adminModel->getLoggedStaffData($suid);

        echo view("team/Templates/header_panel");
        echo view("team/navigation", $data);
        echo view("team/sidebar", $data);
        echo view("team/banners", $data);
        echo view("team/Templates/footer_panel");
    }
```

**View File**

```
        <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="jsdata">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center">Edit Image</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Ad Image</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Upload Date</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Delete Image</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center"><a class="btn bg-success"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                                    <td class="text-center">

    **// The image fetched from database is displayed here //**

                                    <?php if($getad->bannerimg != '') : ?>
                                      <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid" src="<?= $getad->bannerimg; ?>" alt="Ad">
                                      <?php else : ?>
                                      <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid" src="<?= base_url(); ?>/public/assets/img/no-image.png" alt="Ad">
                                      <?php endif; ?>

   **// The image fetched from database is displayed here //**

                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?= $getad->uploaded; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><a class="btn bg-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.card-body -->
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one image in that table then this will return `false`:

```
            if(count($result->getResultArray()) == 1) {
                    return $result->getRow();
            } else {
                    return false;                        
            }
```

So `$data['getad']` and in the view `$getad` will be `false`.  In addition, you fetch an array but then try and access it as an object `$getad->bannerimg`.

Since you only want one row, get rid of the `if` statement and just `return` an object:

```
return $result->getRow();
```

Then in your template, just:

```
<?php if(!empty($getad->bannerimg)) : ?>
```

Comment: First of all, I am extremely sorry i forgot to mention it. But now i have edited my question. Actually i am trying to fetch all the images from database here, this code works but its get only one row.

Comment: Thanks just wrote in a different way instead of using query builder and it worked  public function getBanner() {

                $db = \Config\Database::connect();
                $sql = $db->query('select bannerimg, uploaded from tblbanner');
                $result = $sql->getResult();

                if(count($result) > 0) {

                        return $result;

                } else {

                        return false;
                        
                }
        }